# Find out user and password for user who started a service c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, credentials

I am developing a Windows Application which will be installed as Windows Service.

This installation requires a administrator user and it's password.

Is there any way to recover the user and the password used to start this service in C# *programmatically*?

Comment: @moderator : If this question does not belong here please move it to the right q&a community.

Comment: I really hope it's not. Seems like a serious security breach if the service will have access to the password of the user who started it. Username should probably be accessible. Why would you want the password retrieved inside the service anyway?

Comment: Did you really ask password retrieve ?

Comment: This is a programming question. In fact, it even ends with _programmatically_ .. I see no need to migrate.

Comment: Do you mean the user context in which the service is started, or the user who asked Windows to start the service?  Or the user who installed the service?

Comment: In any case in order to recover passwords in a supported way you would need to install additional components, such as a credential manager.  But I really don't see any legitimate reason for you to want to do this; your users are going to be very cross with you.

Comment: @Harry Johnson : The user context in which the service is started.

Comment: It's not for everyday use , it's a project for my own purpose.

Comment: please vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest supported solution would be to store another copy of the password somewhere, perhaps using [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CryptUnprotectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You might be able to retrieve the password used by the service manager using [LsaRetrievePrivateData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Apparently the name of the secret is the service name (note: the internal service name specified by lpServiceName in CreateService, not the service display name).  It isn't clear what security context you need to be in to do this.  Even if it works, this is not a supported technique.

Or you could install a [credential manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture the password when the service starts.  IIRC, this installation requires a reboot.